# AnyChart 8.1.0 - Resource Gantt - Move periods from one resource to another

Tags: anychart

I am using the AnyChart 8.1.0 resource Gantt (anychart.ganttResource()) to show and edit planned data (car reservations). 
I can edit / move a reservation horizontally to change the time / period of a reservation and also drag the start and/or enddate. But I would like to move a reservation from one car (row) to another - very similar to moving a task from one person to another. 
Is that possible - and how?

Thanks!
Roel

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, and as far as I can see you can use

```
    tree.listen("treeItemMove", function (e) {
                // do your stuff
                });
```

Unfortunally, I think this will only work, if you only have one reservation in each row. If you have more than one, all reservations will be moved.
So far I haven't found a solution to get one reservation and move it to another row. But I hope it may help you in the rigth direction..

EDIT:

I have contacted Anychart support and asked if there is a way to move one period from one (child-) row and create a new row under another parent?

Here is the answer:

*the current version of AnyGantt 8.1.0 doesn't provide this feature as an out-of-the-box or even with the extra code.
But you can modify the dataTree from the code as you need. This provides full control under the data, but without mouse interactivity.*

Answer (score 0):

That's too bad. I can manipulate the tree - even one period, using this code to delete and add a period. You can update a period as well, code should be similar.

```
function deletePeriod( pItemId, pPeriodId ){
  var item = treeData.search("id", pItemId);
  var periods = item.get("periods")
  var i = periods.findIndex(function(e){ return e.id == pPeriodId; });
  periods.splice(i,1);
  item.set('periods', periods);
  treeData.addChildAt( item, treeData.indexOfChild(item) );
}
```

and

```
function addPeriod( pItemId, pPeriodId, start, end){
  var period = {
    "id": pPeriodId,
    "start": start,
    "end": end,
    "name": "Whatever name you want"
  };

  var item = treeData.search("id", pItemId);
  var periods = item.get("periods");
  periods.push(period);
  item.set('periods', periods);
  treeData.addChildAt( item, treeData.indexOfChild(item) );
}
```